# PHP Include based on Array value

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, include, key

I have multiple php files named as following:

- footer-01.php
- footer-02.php
- footer-03.php

and I have this array

```
<?php
    $footer = array(
    1 => "01" // Choose Between 01 to 03
    );
?>
```

I would like to use the value on this array to build up a php include file like the one showing below. the basic idea here is that based on the reference value on this array, a different include syntax would be build.

This is what I came up with but php are showing errors:

```
<?php
    foreach($footer as $key => $item)
    {
    if ($key <> '')
    include '../includes/footer-' . $footer[$key] . '.php';
    }
?>
```

Any ideas on how that can be done? Thanks for help ...

Comment: `> but php are showing errors:`
Which errors do you get?

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with your code. What PHP errors do you get? is the include path correct? And your `if` statement is useless. When you loop over an array then obviously key will never be empty.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. What would be the correct way for this syntax. I'm a newbie with php, so it may seem stupid but I just don't know ...

Comment: The errors: Warning: include(../../includes/omniPro/header-top-.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/nbs/Google Drive/Projects/OMNI-PRO/www/what-we-do/web-design/index.php on line 57

Comment: and:  Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../includes/omniPro/header-top-.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php') in /Users/nbs/Google Drive/Projects/OMNI-PRO/www/what-we-do/web-design/index.php on line 57

Comment: Oops, I've copied the wrong warnings. But they are the same for footer-.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this :

```
<?php
    foreach($footer as $key => $item)
    {
        if ($key <> '')
            include '../includes/footer-' . $item . '.php';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following code $footer[$key] to  $item.
See the complete code.

```
foreach($footer as $key => $item)
{
    if ($key <> '')
    include '../includes/footer-' . $item . '.php';
}
```